# Trying to put images in nodes

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

I am looking to add images inside my nodes on my sigmaJS graph. I know it sounds realy simple but i made a lot of researches and i can't find a correct solution to my problem. I hope someone here can help me !!

I tried a few things including the examples on the official sigmaJS website. But between all the topics already open but talking about an old version of sigmaJS I can't find it anymore. I just want a simple graph of 5 nodes with the same image in each node.

Here is my code if it can help you :

```
<style scoped>
.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
</style>

<template>
  <div class="main">
    <div ref="container" id="container">
      <img src="../assets/city.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Graph from "graphology";
import Sigma from "sigma";
import getNodeProgramImage from "sigma/rendering/webgl/programs/node.image";
import ForceSupervisor from "graphology-layout-force/worker";

export default {
  name: "GraphView",
  mounted() {
    this.rendering();
  },
  methods: {
    rendering() {
      let container = this.$refs.container;
      const graph = new Graph({ multi: true });

      const RED = "#FA4F40";
      const BLUE = "#727EE0";
      const GREEN = "#5DB346";
      graph.addNode("John", {
        size: 15,
        label: "John",
        type: "image",
        image: "../assets/city.png",
        color: RED,
      });
      graph.addNode("Mary", {
        size: 15,
        label: "Mary",
        type: "image",
        image: "./user.svg",
        color: RED,
      });
      graph.addNode("Suzan", {
        size: 15,
        label: "Suzan",
        type: "image",
        image: "./user.svg",
        color: RED,
      });
      graph.addNode("Nantes", {
        size: 15,
        label: "Nantes",
        type: "image",
        image: "./city.svg",
        color: BLUE,
      });
      graph.addNode("New-York", {
        size: 15,
        label: "New-York",
        type: "image",
        image: "./city.svg",
        color: BLUE,
      });
      graph.addNode("Sushis", {
        size: 7,
        label: "Sushis",
        color: GREEN,
      });
      graph.addNode("Falafels", {
        size: 7,
        label: "Falafels",
        color: GREEN,
      });
      graph.addNode("Kouign Amann", {
        size: 7,
        label: "Kouign Amann",
        color: GREEN,
      });
      graph.addEdge("John", "Mary", {
        type: "line",
        label: "works with",
        size: 5,
      });
      graph.addEdge("Mary", "Suzan", {
        type: "line",
        label: "works with",
        size: 5,
      });
      graph.addEdge("Mary", "Nantes", {
        type: "arrow",
        label: "lives in",
        size: 5,
      });
      graph.addEdge("John", "New-York", {
        type: "arrow",
        label: "lives in",
        size: 5,
      });
      graph.addEdge("Suzan", "New-York", {
        type: "arrow",
        label: "lives in",
        size: 5,
      });
      graph.addEdge("John", "Falafels", {
        type: "arrow",
        label: "eats",
        size: 5,
      });
      graph.addEdge("Mary", "Sushis", {
        type: "arrow",
        label: "eats",
        size: 5,
      });
      graph.addEdge("Suzan", "Kouign Amann", {
        type: "arrow",
        label: "eats",
        size: 5,
      });
      graph.nodes().forEach((node, i) => {
        const angle = (i * 2 * Math.PI) / graph.order;
        graph.setNodeAttribute(node, "x", 100 * Math.cos(angle));
        graph.setNodeAttribute(node, "y", 100 * Math.sin(angle));
      });

      const renderer = new Sigma(graph, container, {
        // We don't have to declare edgeProgramClasses here, because we only use the default ones ("line" and "arrow")
        nodeProgramClasses: {
          image: getNodeProgramImage(),
        },
        renderEdgeLabels: true,
      });
      // Create the spring layout and start it
      const layout = new ForceSupervisor(graph);
      layout.start();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hey I want to add images to my nodes too, did you managed to solve it?